# “ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack” with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have this code:

```
def characterize_file(filename):
    try:
        # …
        return (filename, characterization)
    except Exception as e:
        print(filename)
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise e

def write_characterization(args):
    # …
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    characterizations = p.imap(characterize_file, args)
    for (i, (filename, characterization)) in enumerate(characterizations):
        pass # …
```

Sometimes, I get this exception, without any other output:

```
  File "/home/progval/etudes/ens/image/dm/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mogulex/main.py", line 52, in write_characterization
    for (i, (filename, characterization)) in enumerate(characterizations):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 659, in next
    raise value
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Where could it come from? Shouldn't the try statement catch any error and print it?

Comment: Try printing `enumerate(characterizations)` and see how many values are returned.

Comment: nevermind, I just forgot to recompile the code after the last modification. The error was actually from some function called before the try: statement.

Comment: So you should add this as an answer. It might happen to others.